# FieldHistoryArchive

Tags: history-tracking, field-history, archive

I am trying to enable Field Audit Trail and have two questions regarding the FieldHistoryArchive object

1) I can't seem to find the 'FieldHistoryArchive' from object dropdown in workbench after deploy() of object's retention policy. I was able to successfully deploy the package.

2) As I understand it, the FieldHistoryArchive Object stores data for a longer time than the history related list. Is there a reason this object is used especially for storing data and not in the history object?

Comment: can you share your findings?, i'm looking exploring this topic as well.